PHP not writting logs in case of 504
I have a Symfony application and I have set a request_terminate_timeout = 60 to be the same as Nginx timeout, and afterwords for 504 requests I can't see production logs, but if I use prod env locally I can see the logs. Logs are written to php://stdout
In the monolog config, I use the stream handler, so it should not use any buffer but immediately send logs to tty, and locally it send logs right away (again, locally I tested it with prod env), so everything should be fine, right? Here is the Monolog config:
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "%log_path%"
            level: info
            channels: ["!event"]
        console:
            type: console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine"]
        deprecation:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.deprecations.log"
        deprecation_filter:
            type: filter
            handler: deprecation
            max_level: info
            channels: ["php"]

Logpath value:
parameters:
    log_path: "%env(string:default:default_log_path:LOG_DESTINATION)%"

And log destination is equal to php://stdout
Also for the sake of the test, I add logs directly to index.php to omit framework and monolog, like this
(new Dotenv())->bootEnv(dirname(__DIR__) . '/.env');

$logFile = isset($_SERVER['LOG_DESTINATION']) && $_SERVER['LOG_DESTINATION'] !== ''
    ? $_SERVER['LOG_DESTINATION']
    : 'php://stdout';

try {
     file_put_contents(
         $logFile,
         json_encode(
             [
                 'datetime' => (new DateTimeImmutable())->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP'),
                 'message' => 'Request init.',
             ],
             JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR,
         ) . PHP_EOL,
         FILE_APPEND,
     );
} catch (Throwable $e) {
    file_put_contents(
        $logFile,
        '{"message" : "Error writing logs. ' . $e->getMessage() . '."}' . PHP_EOL,
        FILE_APPEND,
    );
}

register_shutdown_function(
    static function () use ($requestId, $logFile, $start): void {
        $errorArray = error_get_last();
        try {
            file_put_contents(
                $logFile,
                json_encode(
                    [
                        'datetime' => (new DateTimeImmutable())->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP'),
                        'message' => 'Request finished.',
                        'last_error' => is_array($errorArray) ? $errorArray : [],
                        'execution_time_ms' => round((microtime(true) - $start) * 1000),
                    ],
                    JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR,
                ) . PHP_EOL,
                FILE_APPEND,
            );
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            file_put_contents(
                $logFile,
                '{"message" : "Error writing logs. ' . $e->getMessage() . '."}' . PHP_EOL,
                FILE_APPEND,
            );
        }
    },
);

Again, I do not see those logs in production, but locally I can see all the logs including this new added to index.php.
Maybe there is a config on the PHP level that controls some buffer or something like that?? Why locally with prod env I see those logs, but on production (that actually uses the same docker image) I see only the Nginx log of about 504 but nothing from the application side?
